# Python : Key doesn't remain pressed when middle-clicking

Tags: python, keyboard, mouse

I'm currently having trouble with a macro I decided to make in Python where if you middle-click while it runs, it will hold down <kbd>C</kbd> for you until you either press the key yourself or if you middle-click a second time. **The issue is that the key is released immediately after pressing**, despite me directly defining that it shouldn't release after pressing *(if active, release, if not, press)*.

I want to remain within the scope of using `mouse` and `keyboard` modules if possible.

Also, I'm not sure if I really have to set up the middle-click handler like how I did, so if there's a better method, sharing it would be appreciated.

Code:

```py
# Modules
import mouse
import keyboard


# Toggle the C key
def toggle():
    active = keyboard.is_pressed('c')
    keyboard.send('c', do_press=not active, do_release=active) # Issue: Presses key just fine, but releases despite it being False.
    print(f"Toggled crouch (prev: {active})")

# Bind toggle function to event
mouse.on_middle_click(callback=toggle)


# Primary function that runs endlessly
def main():
    # Dunno why this is required for the event to work, so...
    mouse.wait(button="MIDDLE", target_types="DOWN")
    pass

# Repeat main() to prevent the program from closing
while True:
    main()
```

I also tried using `keyboard.press` and `keyboard.release` instead of `keyboard.send`, hoping that it would work differently, but it doesn't do anything different from the provided code.